# Maven archetype: Modify artifactId

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

While working on project, my requirement is to create a module.

The command will be like:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeCatalog=local \
  -DartifactId=test-module
```

And the target should have following file structure

```
test-module
|--pom.xml
`--src
   `--main
      |--install
      |  `--install.sh
      `--scripts
         `--test_module.sh
```

My whole goal is to create another variable derived from artifactId (say artifactIdWithUnderscore) replacing all hyphens `-` by underscope `_`. So that I can use the updated variable to create file(s).

Example:

```
+------------------+---------------------------------+
|INPUT - artifactId|OUTPUT - artifactIdWithUnderscore|
+------------------+---------------------------------+
|    test-module   |          test_module            |
|       temp       |             temp                |
| test-temp-module |       test_temp_module          |
+------------------+---------------------------------+
```

I tried to create a new variable as **artifactIdWithUnderscore** by adding following entries in **archetype-metadata.xml**

**Option 1:**

```
<requiredProperty key="artifactIdWithUnderscore" >
  <defaultValue>${StringUtils.replace(${artifactId}, "-", "_")}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Output:

```
${StringUtils.replace(${artifactId}, "-", "_")}
```

**Option 2:**

```
<requiredProperty key="artifactIdWithUnderscore" >
  <defaultValue>${artifactId.replaceAll("-", "_")}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Output:

```
maven_archetype_script
```

The above value of artifactId is coming from the POM of archetype project itself.

**Option 3:**

```
<requiredProperty key="artifactIdWithUnderscore" >
  <defaultValue>${artifactId}.replaceAll("-", "_")</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Output:

```
test-module.replaceAll("-", "_")
```

Please let me know how I can achieve this.

**EDIT**:

**Option 4:**

```
<requiredProperty key="artifactIdWithUnderscore" >
    <defaultValue>${__artifactId__.replaceAll("-", "_")}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Output:

```
INFO: Null reference [template 'artifactIdWithUnderscore', line 1, column 1] : ${__artifactId__.replaceAll("-", "_")} cannot be resolved. 
Define value for property 'artifactIdWithUnderscore': ${__artifactId__.replaceAll("-", "_")}: :
```

Comment: Can you show us your `archetype.properties` file?

Comment: @MattEckert, I don't have `archetype.properties` file. Using `archetype-metadata.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 work for me:

```
<requiredProperty key="artifactIdWithoutDash">
  <defaultValue>${artifactId.replaceAll("-", ".")}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

I can use __artifactIdWithoutDash__.sh has a file name to create the file (in my case it was: some.letters.__artifactIdWithoutDash__.cfg)

Comment: this does not work for me. I got artifactId as the artifactId of architype itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (which is somehow similar) a slightly modified option 2 did the trick:

```
<requiredProperty key="package-with-slash">
    <defaultValue>${package.replace(".", "/")}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Note, that the replacement is done by the [apache velocity engine](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/user-guide.html) and the originally used `replaceAll` uses a regex expression.